# separate list into multiple lists based on property

Tags: c#

I have a List contains items of interface `IGrid` (I created it)

```
public interface IGrid
{
   RowIndex { get; set; }
   ColumnIndex { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to create a method that separates **List** to multiple lists **List>**

based on the RowIndex property

so I wrote:

```
public List<List<IGrid>> Separat(List<IGrid> source)
{
     List<List<IGrid>> grid = new List<List<IGrid>>();
     int max= source.Max(c => c.RowIndex);
     int min = source.Min(c => c.RowIndex);

     for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
     {
          var item = source.Where(c => c.RowIndex == i).ToList();
           if (item.Count > 0)
                grid.Add(item);
           }
           return grid;
     }
}
```

What is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with LINQ in a single statement:

```
public List<List<IGrid>> Separat(List<IGrid> source) {
    return source
        .GroupBy(s => s.RowIndex)
        .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
        .Select(g => g.ToList())
        .ToList();
}
```

If you do not care that the lists appear in the ascending order of `RowIndex`, the way that your method produces them, you can remove the `OrderBy` method call from the chain of method invocations.

Comment: what is the complexity of this statement?  Is this going to blow up if I have large lists?

Comment: @DanB This isn't overly expensive - the most expensive one is `OrderBy`, which is O(n*log n) in the worst case (when groups are of size 1). Grouping part is O(n).